# Dynamic Arrays passing to functions

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, dynamic

I have created 2 dynamic arrays in the main function. I have passed both of them to the function by reference. Then I copy data from smaller dynamic array to the larger dynamic array. I delete the smaller dynamic array. Assign the address of the larger dynamic array to the smaller dynamic array. Now ideally the arr array should have size of 10. However, when I try to print the 6th element of the array in the main, it crashes. Please have a look at the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std; 

void func(string * arr, string * brr); 

int main()             
{ 
    string* arr = new string[5]; 
    arr[0] = "hello0"; 
    arr[1] = "hello1"; 
    arr[2] = "hello2"; 
    arr[3] = "hello3"; 
    arr[4] = "hello4"; 

    string* brr = new string[10]; 


    func(arr, brr); 

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
        cout << arr[i] << endl; 

    return 0; 
} 

void func(string * arr, string * brr) 
{ 
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        brr[i] = arr[i]; 

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        cout << brr[i] << endl; 

    delete []arr; 

    arr = brr; 

    arr[5] = "hello5";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This line has absolutely no effect for the caller:

```
arr = brr;
```

So after the call, **`arr` points exactly where it used to point before** - to a now invalid memory area (because you deleted it).

If this would be a C question, I would advise you to use a pointer to a pointer (`string **arr`). However, I feel this is nasty in a C++ program. Maybe you want to use a reference somewhere ?

Comment: It's not nasty at all, but you can use a reference to a pointer, if you want: void func(string*& arr, string * brr)

Comment: @Asaf I know little C++ myself but I always thought idiomatic C++ avoids pointers. Nice suggestion though.

Comment: [Good Article on This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4894/Pointer-to-Pointer-and-Reference-to-Pointer)

Comment: The advantage I see for ref-to-ptr (as the article calls them), or of any reference over passing a pointer to a parameter that you want to modify inside the function is that you can't pass NULL by accident (in this case - &arr - the address of arr - is always valid). Sometimes I prefer ptr-to-ptr for flexibility (The calling code does not have to supply an output param). In any case, my response to the approach that says "idiomatic C++ avoids pointers" is: This is C++. If you don't want to use pointers, use C#.

Answer (score 2):

Set this signature for the function

```
void func(string * & arr, string * & brr)
```

Answer (score 0):

@cnicutar correctly diagnosed the problem; you'll either need to pass arr by reference (reference to the POINTER, not the array), of have fund return the new value of arr, which the caller can assign.

Comment: Technically, you weren't passing arr by reference before: you were passing a pointer by value (which is why changes TO the pointer had no effect outside of the function).  The & means pass by reference, and can be applied to anything.

Comment: Yeah I think I get it. So by adding the extra &, whatever changes I make in the function would also effect the "arr" array in the main. Thanks alot. Its actually a pretty simple fix. I added quite a bit of code to circumvent this problem.