# Crash when trying to dynamically resize an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator, delete-operator

Right now, I want to increase the size of the array using a function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void IncreaseArraySize(int* addr){
    int* temp = new int[20];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        temp[i] = addr[i];
    }
    for(int i=10;i<20;i++){
        temp[i] = i;
    }
    int* dummy = addr;
    addr = temp;
    delete[] dummy;
}

int main(){
    int* test = new int[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        test[i] = i;
    }
    IncreaseArraySize(test);
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        cout<<"at index "<<i<<"we have"<<test[i]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"ok!"<<endl;
    delete[] test;
}
```

I ran the code with:
valgrind --leak-check=full ./test 2>debug.txt

and this is what I got for the output:

```
at index 0we have0
at index 1we have1
at index 2we have2
at index 3we have3
at index 4we have4
at index 5we have5
at index 6we have6
at index 7we have7
at index 8we have8
at index 9we have9
at index 10we have0
at index 11we have0
at index 12we have0
at index 13we have0
at index 14we have0
at index 15we have0
at index 16we have0
at index 17we have0
at index 18we have112
at index 19we have0
ok!
```

and this is what I got at the debug.txt:

```
==4285== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4285== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4285== Using Valgrind-3.6.1-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4285== Command: ./test
==4285== 
==4285== Invalid read of size 4
==4285==    at 0x400997: main (test.cpp:24)
==4285==  Address 0x596f040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd
==4285==    at 0x4C27C6E: operator delete[](void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:409)
==4285==    by 0x400931: IncreaseArraySize(int*) (test.cpp:14)
==4285==    by 0x400980: main (test.cpp:22)
==4285== 
==4285== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
==4285==    at 0x4C27C6E: operator delete[](void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:409)
==4285==    by 0x400A16: main (test.cpp:27)
==4285==  Address 0x596f040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd
==4285==    at 0x4C27C6E: operator delete[](void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:409)
==4285==    by 0x400931: IncreaseArraySize(int*) (test.cpp:14)
==4285==    by 0x400980: main (test.cpp:22)
==4285== 
==4285== 
==4285== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4285==     in use at exit: 80 bytes in 1 blocks
==4285==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 120 bytes allocated
==4285== 
==4285== 80 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==4285==    at 0x4C2864B: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:305)
==4285==    by 0x4008A9: IncreaseArraySize(int*) (test.cpp:5)
==4285==    by 0x400980: main (test.cpp:22)
==4285== 
==4285== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4285==    definitely lost: 80 bytes in 1 blocks
==4285==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4285==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4285==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4285==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4285== 
==4285== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4285== ERROR SUMMARY: 22 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Could you explain this in newbie terms?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9167540/535275

Comment: `addr = temp;` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I thought addr=temp was supposed to copy what the temp is holding (since temp is a pointer, address to some heap space) to addr...guess c++'s too confusing to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that your problem is that because you are passing the pointer to the start of the array by value, once you've updated and reassigned it, the changes aren't propagating to the caller.  If you change the function so that it takes the pointer by reference, this should be fixed:

```
void IncreaseArraySize(int*& addr){
```

Right now, your bug is caused because when you call

```
IncreaseArraySize(test);
```

The `test` pointer back in `main` isn't getting reassigned.  As a result, once you `delete[]` it in `IncreaseArraySize`, it references garbage memory.  Updating the parameter so that it's passed by reference means that when, in `IncreaseArraySize`, you say

```
addr = temp;
```

This will update the `test` pointer in `main`, preventing the bug.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Well the most appropriate way to correct this code is to not use `new` at all, just use:
**[std:vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)**

Also, the problem with your code in particular is that you are passing the pointer `addr` by value, which creates a temporary and passes it to the function. Any changes made to this pointer inside the function are made on the copy of the pointer and not the original pointer.You need `addr` by reference, so that the changes inside the function are made on the pointer and get reflected outside the function.

```
void IncreaseArraySize(int*& addr)
```

Comment: @user269334: Actually, consider using the first suggestion as well, that is more appropriate, ofcourse the `&` would matter even when you pass `std::vector` to the function.Do Lookup *Pass by Value vs Pass by References* in C++.